# What is the HOMING operator?

Tags: classification, feature-extraction, ocr, dynamic-programming

I was reading ["Optical Recognition Systems" book](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/74d6/68256131f379d63a3d484ccff513f5bbb6d3.pdf) and in chapter 3.3.2.3 where methods for full genetic programming are described, [a paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/298829) is describing an ADF (automatically defined functions) like this:

> The ADFs have the terminal set Tf ={X, N, S, W, E, NE, NW, SE, SW} and the
>   function set Ff = {AND, OR, NOT}. The main program has the terminal set Tc = {I,
>   L, NIL} and a set of functions (Fc) containing movement functions, logical operators,
>   four ADFs and the HOMING operator.

I am confused about the meaning of HOMING operator. An explanation or some links to point me in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1993 paper by [John R. Koza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Koza) (a pioneer of genetic programming), [Simultaneous Discovery of Detectors and a Way of Using the Detectors via Genetic Programming](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.50.1005&rep=rep1&type=pdf), can be accessed on CiteSeer. The HOMING operator is described as:

> The one-argument HOMING operator evaluates its argument and, in
>   addition, has the side effect of rubber-banding the turtle to its
>   position at the start of the evaluation of the HOMING. HOMING is
>   equivalent to the brackets in a Lindenmayer system.

From my limited understanding, it is a formal programming operator, within which a certain number of instructions are performed (like motion to North, East, South-West, etc.). It memorizes some initial state (or bookmark), and returns to it when all inner instructions have been executed. In the paper context, it refers to a turtle moving from pixel to pixel to detect a letter in a pixel grid. At the end of its journey, the turtle shall go back to its original location (rubber-banding), or HOME.

Maybe the illustration of  the bracket effect in an [L-system (Lindenmayer system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) given in section Turtle branching from [Drawing simple generative organics with L-systems](https://www.vexlio.com/blog/drawing-simple-organics-with-l-systems/) can help a bit:

[image: https://twitter.com/i/status/1208386711249735680]